# Error : Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'UserDefinedLocalization-Info.plist'

Tags: iphone, xcode

When I run the Application then warning display below,

> Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'UserDefinedLocalization-Info.plist'.

Comment: I got the solution from this similar question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095612/warning-the-copy-bundle-resources-build-phase-contains-this-targets-info-plist

Answer (score 35):

I had this issue after I rearranged the underlying file structure of my project. Xcode4 has moved things around though and most online help to this problem is Xcode 3 specific, so this is how you solve this in Xcode 4:

- Click the project icon in the Project Navigator (the blue root icon)
- In your main pane menu you should be able to choose between your project or targets, select the target
- Select "Build Phases" in the top menu
- Open the "Copy bundle resources" item
- Remove your plist file from there (your plist file should not be copied as a part of the bundle)

Comment: This should be selected as answer if you're using XCode 4.

Comment: This works on xCode 5 as well! Should be the accepted answer for sure.

Comment: Works on xCode 6 too.

Comment: Here the official explanation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1649/_index.html

Answer (score 6):

In xcode, right click the `UserDefinedLocalization-Info.plist` file, select `Get Info`. Go to the `Targets` tab and remove the checkmark in front of your target.

The info.plist is a special file and must be treated in a special way. It's not allowed to add it to the app in the normal way.

Comment: I don't believe that works in Xcode 4. I have the same problem as Rahul, but I can't go to "get info" for the plist file in Xcode 4.

Comment: @Gorgando: In Xcode 4 open the utilities view and look for "Target Membership".