# Coding / running Ruby in XCode

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos

I am currently using TextMate for OS X to create basic Ruby code (still learning), saving down as a .rb file and using Terminal to run the basic code.

I was just wondering if its possible for me to use XCode for this task at all?  I am assuming not from what I've been reading but if it is does anyone know of a guide of how to set this up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [MacRuby](http://www.macruby.org/). The current stable version has Xcode integration. It does need a 64-bit system running Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a simple ruby script:

```
if let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "my_script", withExtension: "rb") {
  let task = Process()

  task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
  task.arguments = ["ruby", file.path, "arg1"]

  let pipe = Pipe()
  task.standardOutput = pipe
  task.launch()

  let data:Data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
  if let output = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
    print(output)
  }
}
```

make sure you have the `my_script.rb` file resource copied as a build resource -  [Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095612/warning-the-copy-bundle-resources-build-phase-contains-this-targets-info-plist#answer-3095716)