# iPhone build programming

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095612/warning-the-copy-bundle-resources-build-phase-contains-this-targets-info-plist)

There is no build issue problem in program.But,When i try to run on simulator it show two error.

```
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'CalCulator/CalCulator-Info.plist'.
```

I'm not understanding, why this errors are showing?

Update:I solved the errors.but why this is showing?

```
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Thanks in advice

Comment: Agreed, duplicate. Check out that question, Yasir! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler warning (or error) is 100% accurate.

> The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file

You accidentally added your projects Info.plist file to your project target.

Select your Info.plist file in the left sidebar. Open the File Inspector in the right sidebar and remove the checkmarks in the "Target Membership" section.