# The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'Info.plist' in xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am getting this warning  `The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'Info.plist'`.I have read the solution [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1649/_index.html) It says that Info.plist file has been copied into **copy bundle resources** & i have to remove it from there.But i don't find any **Info.plist**.Please suggest what to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095612/warning-the-copy-bundle-resources-build-phase-contains-this-targets-info-plist)

Answer (score 16):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1649/_index.html

The Apple documentation says you just remove the info.plist file from the following phase.

1. Click the target of project
2. Select the item of Build Phase
3. Then select the item of Copy Bundle Resources
4. Final remove this file from you selected file

Clear the project and rebuild it.

Answer (score 2):

You can find your info.plist file in folder called as Supporting Files folder which is automatically created.

or

you can also find info.plist file in your target -> info

check this link

[Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095612/warning-the-copy-bundle-resources-build-phase-contains-this-targets-info-plist)

Hope it helps.

Comment: It says i have to remove Info.plist from copy bundle resources but there is no info.plist in copy bundle resources

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful for someone.

In my Flutter Application.
I opened iOS Module in xCode and clicked on Info.plist file and unchecked  Target Membership (Runner) in the File Inspector on left side.
I am using 10.3

Answer (score 0):

Select Your Project And Go To Build Phases
Step One: Open (Link Binary With Libraries) And Make Sure No Duplicate.
Step Two: Open (Embed Pods Frameworks) and make Sure No Duplicate For input and output files.
Step Three: Open (Copy Pods Resources) and make Sure No Duplicate For input and output files.
Step Four: Open (Embed Frameworks) And Make Sure No Duplicate.