# What means iOS Xcode plist warning?

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, compiler-warnings

What means this Xcode warning?

**Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase 
 contains this target's Info.plist file 'Info.plist'**

Comment: Have you tried googling this? The first several results are stack overflow questions that have answers http://stackoverflow.com/q/3095612/934912 followed by a page on apple's site with the same info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My be you info.plist file copied in "Copy Bundle Resources". see this image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjCjI.jpg

simply delete this file.

Answer (score 0):

As the warning states your `Copy Bundle Resources` contains your applications `info.plist` file. You need to remove it from there.

For removing it:

```
Choose your target --> Go to Build Phases --> Check the Copy Bundle Resources tab--> Choose your info.plist from there --> Click on **-** button
```

[image]